# Homogenizing scale for density plot

Tags: r, kernel-density, spatstat, r-base-graphics

I am making a series of plots from a point pattern (PPP) with the density (kernel) function. I would like that the maximum plotted number is 200 in all cases and just the heatmap accordingly (two of the images only go up to 100). I have not been able to find a solution to this problem using the R base plot.

```
    Microglia_Density <- density(Microglia_PPP, sigma =0.1, equal.ribbon = TRUE, col = topo.colors, main = "")
plot(Microglia_Density, main = "Microglia density")

Astrocytes_Density <- density(Astrocytes_PPP, sigma =0.1, equal.ribbon = TRUE, col = topo.colors, main = "")
plot(Astrocytes_Density, main = "Astrocytes density")

Neurons_Density <- density(Neurons_PPP, sigma =0.1, equal.ribbon = TRUE, col = topo.colors, main = "")
plot(Neurons_Density, main = "Neuronal density")
```

I would appreciate recommendations. Regards

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Could you make a small reproducible example? You tagged your question `spatstat` and mentioned that your data are PPPs... but I'm not sure what subpackages are being used. Looks like `density.ppp` is in the `spatstat.core` package and it returns a `density.ppp` object so the next function to find is the `plot.density.ppp` function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don’t have access to your data I simulate fake data in a square.
There are several options to do what you want. First you should know that
`density()` is a generic function, so when you invoke it on a `ppp` like
`Microglia_PPP` actually the function `density.ppp()` is invoked.
This function returns an `im` object (effectively a 2-d “image” of values).
You plot this with `plot()` which in turn calls `plot.im()`, so you should
read the help file of `plot.im()`, where it says that the argument `col`
controls the colours used in the plot. Either you can make a colour map
covering the range of values you are interested in and supply that, or if you
know that one of the images has the colour map you want to use you can save
it and reuse for the others:

```r
library(spatstat)
set.seed(42)
Microglia_PPP <- runifpoint(100)
Neurons_PPP <- runifpoint(200)
Neurons_Density <- density(Neurons_PPP, sigma = 0.1)
Microglia_Density <- density(Microglia_PPP, sigma = 0.1)
my_colourmap <- plot(Neurons_Density, main = "Neuronal density", col = topo.colors)
```

[image]

```r
plot(Microglia_Density, main = "Microglia density", col = my_colourmap)
```

[image]

Notice the colour maps are the same, but it only covers the range from
approximately 80 to 310. Any values of the image outside this range will not
be plottet, so they appear white.

You can make a colour map first and then use it for all the plots
(see `help(colourmap)`):

```r
my_colourmap <- colourmap(topo.colors(256), range = c(40,315))
plot(Neurons_Density, main = "Neuronal density", col = my_colourmap)
```

[image]

```r
plot(Microglia_Density, main = "Microglia density", col = my_colourmap)
```

[image]

Finally another solution if you want the images side by side is to make them
an `imlist` (image list) and use `plot.imlist()` with `equal.ribbon = TRUE`:

```r
density_list <- as.imlist(list(Neurons_Density, Microglia_Density))
plot(density_list, equal.ribbon = TRUE, main = "")
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your support. That was the solution I was looking for. It worked perfectly establishing a colormap as you suggested. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please go ahead and accept the answer by pressing the checkmark so the question appears as solved for future searches.